# npm install hangs on "buildDeps"

Tags: node.js, npm

Since today, `npm install` hangs on the `buildDeps` step. It worked fine yesterday but ceased to work today. No updates of any kind had been done in the meantime, i.e. I do not see any reason why it simply stopped to work.

It also does not fail just for a single, specific package or project, the install also fails for other packages and when installing something globally. I have tried deleting the `package-lock.json`.

It does not hang forever, but for very long (several minutes). Eventually, a timeout error will be thrown. This error is not always thrown by the "buildDeps" stage, sometimes npm is able to go past this stage (after several minutes, as mentioned).

I am using Arch Linux and npm v8.5.5. I have done a complete system-update since the error started to occur, the problem remained the same.

Below you can find the complete logs of npm's verbose output.

```
npm verb cli [    
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',    
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/npm',    
npm verb cli   'i',    
npm verb cli   '@reactjs/toolkit',    
npm verb cli   'redux',    
npm verb cli   'immer',    
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@8.5.5
npm info using node@v17.9.0
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/home/.../.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/home/.../.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/usr/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 6ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 6ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
npm verb logfile /home/.../.npm/_logs/2022-04-23T18_55_05_128Z-debug-0.log
npm timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 16ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 892ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 1ms
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠧ idealTree:generator-ui: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

Comment: On my case the cause was a network instability. #! Share us your package json #2 Try it in another network like a cloud or a contact laptop to determine if it is a nodejs error or your home network error.